# should i use a decorator to provide a subclass to multiple classes in python

Tags: python, django, decorator

I have a subclass baz, which needs to be included in both foo and bar,

```
class foo():
   def __init__()
     pass

   class baz:
     pass


class bar():
   def __init__()
     pass

   class baz:
     pass
```

I imagine in this situation a decorator could wrap around both foo and bar, providing baz to each, but i can't seem to find any examples for writing such a decorator.

pointers?

Comment: Without more specifics on why both of these would need the same inner class, it's tough to say.  Are you sure they don't just both need an instance of this class?

Comment: Definitely not a job for decorators, even in the highly unlikely case that you really need a inner class ...

Comment: in django each model is a class, and needs to have an inner 
Admin, i just thought i'd save code by using a decorator

Comment: Either you're using a very old (pre-1.0) version of Django or you're doing it wrong :)  These days you use `ModelAdmin` classes - http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: Is the "inner Admin" really a `class` of which there could be more than a single instance of per each model class?

Comment: i was trying to do this: http://blog.disqus.net/2007/03/11/a-django-primer/

Comment: That blog post is three and a half years old, and Django has changed drastically since then.  You'll want to just use the latest version and follow its tutorial - http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: gret, thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reiterate the comments, **don't** use this method to create Admin objects for Django, upgrade to a later, greater version of Django :)

FWIW a decorator to do what you asked would look something like:

```
def add_baz(klass):
    def adder():
        instance = klass()

        class Baz:
            bazvar='This is an attribute of Baz'

        instance.Baz = Baz

        return instance
    return adder

@add_baz
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

>>> myfoo = Foo()
>>> myfoo.Baz
<class __main__.Baz at 0x9f213ec>
>>> myfoo.Baz.bazvar
'This is an attribute of Baz'
```